# Aligning vertical range slider with buttons at its end

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a zoom slider with a vertical range slider and two buttons at either end but am unable to horizontally align the slider with the buttons at its ends.

```css
#zoomcontrol {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#zoomrange,
#minus,
#plus {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

#zoomrange {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}

#minus {
  top: 180px;
}

#minus,
#plus {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomcontrol">
  <div id="plus">+</div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="zoomrange" orient="vertical">
  <div id="minus">-</div>
</div>
```

(Also, could someone please tell me why the minus button further away from the slider than the plus button?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compensate for the width of the buttons and their margin, plus the width of `#zoomrange` itself.

```
#minus, #plus {
  left: calc(50% - 16px);
  transform: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using flexbox can help a bit along with the absolute positioning;

```css
#zoomcontrol {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#zoomrange,
#minus,
#plus {}

#zoomrange {
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}

#minus,
#plus {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomcontrol">
  <div id="plus">+</div>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="zoomrange" orient="vertical">
  <div id="minus">-</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example with a flex container and justify-content.

```css
.zoom-container {
  width: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.zoom-range {
  width: 100%;
  writing-mode: bt-lr;
  -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
}

.zoom-control {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="zoom-container">
    <button class="zoom-control" id="plus">+</button>
    <input class="zoom-range" id="range" type="range" step="10" value="50" orient="vertical">
    <button class="zoom-control" id="minus">-</button>
    <output for="range" id="output">50</output>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/weog8y3a/